# Opening APK fails due to java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android, java

I have an APK file that, regardless of where I install it (emulator and device alike), crashes before even starting, with the message "Unfortunately, The APK Name has stopped."

To figure a way to fix the issue, I have run the APK in a device, collected to logs and `grep`ed the logs pertaining to APK itself.

The log repeatedly shows the following pattern:

```
03-30 17:51:57.347 12196 12196 E AndroidRuntime: Process: the.apk.name, PID: 12196
03-30 17:51:57.347 12196 12196 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class the.apk.name.lorem: java.lang.Object the.apk.name.lorem.ipsum(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) failed to verify: java.lang.Object the.apk.name.lorem.ipsum(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]): [0x152] type Conflict unexpected as arg to if-eqz/if-nez (declaration of 'the.apk.name.lorem' appears in /data/app/the.apk.name-2/base.apk)
```

What I would like to do is to run this APK file properly, in either an emulator or a device, preferably with changing configurations in the environment rather than the APK itself. What to do?

Comment: Was this APK build with Android Studio ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout I do not know. I received the APK as is with no details.

Comment: I do not understand how you expect this to work. Whatever the problem is, it will 99% of the time require you to rebuild the app, or change something in the code. If you only have the APK there's nothing you can do. It's like having a `.exe` file that throws a Segmentation fault, and you want to magically fix it without any source whatsoever ..

Comment: @ArthurAttout lets say I do reverse the APK, what then?

Comment: If you wish to do that, you can try, then ask a new question with specific problem you have with your reverse-engineering processing (and probably ask that question on [ReverseEngineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com)).

Comment: (btw if the APK you've been given by 'someone' from 'somewhere' and you have 'no details' about, has been obfuscated, then your reverse-engineering process will be **a complete nightmare**)